# Return data Ajax - Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to return data from a table using Mysql and Ajax, but got nothing in the variable. Connexion to database is Ok and the query is ok too.

The table contains 2 ids, which I'm trying to retrieve :

[image]

process.php

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','DBB');
   if (!$con) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }


   $sql="SELECT id FROM events";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

   echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

The Ajax function

```
<script>
function print() {

    $.ajax({  
         url: "process.php",   
         dataType: 'json',
         success : function(data)
         {
             console.log(data); // OUTPUT
         } 
    });
}
</script>
```

Output

```
Object {current_field: null, field_count: null, lengths: null, num_rows: null, type: null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $result variable in PHP doesn't actually return the IDs, you have to iterate through it to get the IDs like so:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','DBB');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }


    $sql = "SELECT id FROM events";
    $ids = array();
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $ids[] = $obj->id;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($ids);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I will try to write an ID in the database now

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each row:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','DBB');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }


    $sql = "SELECT id FROM events";
    $rows  = array();
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        while ($row= $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);

   $result->close();
   $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: With your code, array returned contains nothing. The solution of B.Aikey works

Comment: This should give you array of all the objects selected in the query in JSON format